# Running PyQGIS script in secondary thread

Tags: pyqgis, performance

My script works but its execution is very slow and it freezes QGIS.

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

_NAME_FIELD = 'index' # numero bt
_H_FIELD = 'h'      # hauteur bt
_SUM_FIELD = 'h'    # somme hauteurs bts voisins

_NEW_NEIGHBORS_FIELD = 'NEIGHBORS' # numero des bts voisins
_NEW_H_NEIGHBORS_FIELD = 'H_N' # hauteur des bts voisins
_NEW_SUM_FIELD = 'SUM_H' # somme hauteur des bts voisins

layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()
layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(
       [QgsField(_NEW_NEIGHBORS_FIELD, QVariant.String),
       QgsField(_NEW_H_NEIGHBORS_FIELD, QVariant.String),
       QgsField(_NEW_SUM_FIELD, QVariant.Int)])

layer.updateFields()
feature_dict = {f.id(): f for f in layer.getFeatures()}

index = QgsSpatialIndex()
for f in feature_dict.values():
   index.insertFeature(f)
   
for f in feature_dict.values():
   print ('Working on %s' % f[_NAME_FIELD])
   
   geom = f.geometry()
   intersecting_ids = index.intersects(geom.boundingBox())
   
   neighbors = []
   h_n = []
   neighbors_sum = 0
   
   for intersecting_id in intersecting_ids:
       intersecting_f = feature_dict[intersecting_id]
       if (f != intersecting_f and
           not intersecting_f.geometry().disjoint(geom)):
           neighbors.append(intersecting_f[_NAME_FIELD])
           h_n.append(intersecting_f[_H_FIELD])
           neighbors_sum += intersecting_f[_SUM_FIELD]
   f[_NEW_NEIGHBORS_FIELD] = ','.join(map(str, neighbors))
   f[_NEW_H_NEIGHBORS_FIELD] = ','.join(map(str, h_n))
   #f[_NEW_H_NEIGHBORS_FIELD] = ','.join([str(x) for t in h_n for x in t])     
   f[_NEW_SUM_FIELD] = neighbors_sum
   layer.updateFeature(f)
layer.commitChanges()
print ('Processing complete.')
```

I read that the solution is to use one or more secondary threads.
The more I read on this subject, the more everything seems confusing to me, and I cannot understand how it is organized in concrete terms.

What would be a suitable method?

Comment: What is it supposed to do

Comment: @bera : my layer contains more than 300,000 polygons (buildings).
The script creates 3 variables for each building:
the list of adjoining buildings (Neigbors), the list of heights* of neighboring buildings (H_N) (*in reality these are classes), the sum of the heights (SUM_H).
I imagine a secondary thread would prevent the Qgis window from freezing. I intuitively imagine that if the calculations are carried out using several secondary threads, the execution will be faster. But I can't figure out how it works in my case.

Comment: Have you tried index.addFeatures(layer.getFeatures()) so you don't have to extract from the dictionary and insert the features one by one?
You should also implement GEOS, together with the spatial index will give you the best performance.